# How to find Arg's type on decompiled dll

Tags: c++, dll, arguments, void-pointers, decompiling

I have decompiled a DLL to find all argument's of one of the entries function and it look's like that :

```
void** FunctionImLookingFor(void** ecx, void** a2, void** a3, void** a4, void** a5, void** a6, void** a7) {
    void* ebp8;
    void** eax9;
    void** v10;
    int1_t zf11;
    void** eax12;
    void** v13;
    int1_t zf14;
    void** edx15;
    int1_t zf16;
    void** v17;
    void** eax18;
    void** ecx19;
    void** v20;
...
}
```

All parameters are void** and it make no sense. Is it normal ? How could I figure what kind of args it was ? do I did something wrong during my decompilation ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A dll does not contain such information - it's not required for running the code, only during compilation.

Comment: Humm, seems logic, Thank's for the awnser